# Comparing dates - Converted string changing date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, compare

I have the below code:

```
function CheckDOB(DOB)
{
  var d = new Date();

  var curr_date = d.getDate();
  var curr_month = d.getMonth();
  var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

  var dobDate = new Date(DOB);
  var dobDay = dobDate.getDate();
  var dobMonth = dobDate.getMonth();
  var dobYear = dobDate.getFullYear() 

  DOB = new Date(dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear );

  console.log("DOB: " + DOB);

  var today  = Date(curr_date, curr_month, curr_year);

  console.log("Today: "+ today);

  if (DOB >= today)
  {
    console.log("in false");
    alert("Date of Birth cannot be greater than today.");
    alert = function(){};
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("in true");
    return true;
  }
}

function txtCompPersonDOB_OnChange()
{
   var DOB = CSForm.getField('txtCompPersonDOB').getValue();
   //console.log(DOB);

   if(CheckDOB(DOB)) 
   {
      console.log("test on change: false")
      CSForm.getField('txtCompPersonDOB').setFocus();
   }    
   else
   {
    console.log("test on changeL true");
   }

}
```

I am using an old version of LiquidOffice, which allows you to create eForms using JavaScript.

The date is getting picked bu a Date Picker (in string format) and then I am converting it to date using the `CheckDOB()` function.

These are the `console.log()` results:

[image]

For some reason the dates are not appearing correctly and the comparison is off. the DOB picked is `27/01/2018` but in the console logged it is shown as `10/09/1906`

Can anyone tell me what I am missing or doing wrong from my end?

The alerts don't get triggered for some reason, and the date does not match that of the selection.

Comment: What is the output when you log DOB itself. Before you pass it to the new Date() constructor?

Comment: @OdamePrince It is `27/01/2018` (exactly as written)

Comment: You are attempting something like `new Date("27/01/2018")`. See the duplicate.